# Navbar wont align with content

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create an HTML page but the content only starts below where the line of the left nav bar finished. i am trying to get the twi to line next to each other. I have tried floating the content but no luck so far

Heres my CSS, any help is greatly appreciated

```
    body
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #0099CC;
    background-image: url(../Images/Background.jpg);
}

#banner
{
    background-color: #87CEFA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    text-align: center;
}
#banner h1
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: .5em;
}

#container
{
    margin: 1em 5%;
    background-color: #E0FFFF;
    background-image: url(../Images/bluebackground.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#content
{
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 2em 0 200px; 
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    float:left; 
}


#navigation {float:left; font-size:0.75em; width:178px; }
#navigation ul {margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#navigation li {list-style: none;}

ul.top-level { background:#1E90FF; }

ul.top-level li {
 border-bottom: #fff solid;
 border-top: #fff solid;
 border-width: 1.5px;

}

#navigation a {
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
 display:block;
 height:25px;
 line-height: 25px;
 text-indent: 10px;                   
 text-decoration:none;
 width:100%;
}

#navigation a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}
#navigation li:hover {
 background: #f90;
 position: relative;

 }
ul.sub-level { 
    display: none;
}

li:hover .sub-level {
    background: #0000CD;
    border: #fff solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 168px;
    top: 0px;
}

ul.sub-level li {
    border: none;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
}

#nav p
{ 
    margin-top: 0; 
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
    background-color: #78CEFA;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    font-size:1em;
}
```

Comment: May be useful if you post the html also

Comment: plz create a fiddle and post your code there!!

Comment: Create your fiddle here > http://jsfiddle.net/ :)

Comment: hello sorry never used jsfiddle hope this works http://jsfiddle.net/zNQkF/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
#content
{
padding-top: 0.5em;
margin: 0 2em 0 200px; 
padding-bottom: 0.5em;
float: left;
}
```

to this:

```
#content
{
padding-top: 0.5em;
margin: 0 2em 0 200px; 
padding-bottom: 0.5em;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

(That is, change `float: left;` to `overflow: hidden;`)